# How can I pass my get request into my res.render?

Tags: node.js, express, get

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const request = require('request');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {

    request({
        url: 'https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds',
        auth: {
            'bearer': req.user.accessToken
        }
    }, function (err, res) {
        console.log(res.body);
        //How can I pass the res.body from here
    });

    res.render('dashboard', {user: req.user servers: /*into here?*/});
});

module.exports = router;
```

How can I pass my get request into my res.render? So I can output it using ejs.

Answer (score 0):

`res.render` should be called in a place where necessary data is available.  If this place is `request` callback then that's it. Since there are different `res` objects in different function scopes, then need to be named to not be shadowed:

```
request({
    url: 'https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds',
    auth: {
        'bearer': req.user.accessToken
    }
}, function (err, response) {
   res.render('dashboard', {user: req.user, servers: response.body});
});
```